# Does it make sense to encrypt every value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, encryption

I currently have a MySQL database without built in database encryption. I am aware that encryption is available, but it's not available on AWS RDS for the instance size I'm working with.

Instead, I plan to utilize AWS KMS (basically standard hashing encryption) to hash every single value before entering it in the datable. I am working with sensitive data that needs to be HIPAA compliant.

My question is, by hashing the values, this essentially renders querying useless right? Additionally, if that's the case, what would be the difference between hashing every value (first name, last name, DOB, etc..) vs. treating the entire row as a single JSON string, and then hashing that (and storing in a single column).

If anyone has experience encrypting on the application level with HIPAA/sensitive data and storing it in MySQL, I'd appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Encrypting everything is a bit excessive and I don't think it is a HIPPA requirement. I also wouldn't put all the user info in an encrypted JSON. That method would make search a bit slower because to search on last name, you have unencrypt each row to do the comparisons and each row could contain a lot of info

Comment: @CptMisery Yeah that's exactly what I was thinking. I figure there should be a better approach.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure what the best method is, but the encrypt/decrypt functions in MySQL are easy to use and run very quickly. I've used them for SSNs and credit card info. So getting your own server or a better AWS would be a good idea.

Comment: I have read that for the best (maybe debatable) security is to have 3 servers. A database server, a web server, and a server with an API that the web side uses to talk to the DB side. With this setup, a hacker only sees the web server and they have to break into it to see the middle server. Then they have to break into the middle server to get the encryption password and access to the DB server.

Comment: The way I have it set up now is that I have a back end server that separately communicates with the database. What I ultimately plan to do is just encrypt the database and allow just the backend server to reach it.

Answer (score 1):

While I've worked on a few HIPPA projects in the past I'm in no way an expert. HIPAA has a lot of components you need to take into account so take the following as non HIPPA specific.

I would consider operating your own relational DB server with full disc and database encryption or (if your able to just work with JSON strings anyway) use a NOSQL DB like dynamo DB.

The last project I worked on kept data in an encrypted relational DB and locked it down (we hired security engineers for that) however on the application level we didn't encrypt anything.

I would try to avoid encrypting on the application level if possible as it leads to added complexity

Lastly, you might find this link useful
https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/compliance/AWS_HIPAA_Compliance_Whitepaper.pdf

as well as this tool for managing PHI with dynamoDB
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-dynamodb-encryption-java

Comment: I definitely prefer working with MySQL just because that's what everyone here is familiar with, and we'll likely be running plenty of queries on the data. I looked through the link, and it seems like it might be worth it to just go with the larger RDS instance size for the added encryption option..I'm definitely  not comfortable running up a MySQL server and encrypting it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I work as a DB encryption consultant and in your case I recommend using a Column-based encryption solution. That way you will be able to select which columns contain sensitive information, define column-specific enc/dec and access control policies and of course have different keys for each column.

Since you are using MySQL, you may want to check out [MyDiamo](https://mydiamo.com/), there is a trial license for the solution. I have deployed it on a number of occasions where clients were specifically targeting HIPAA compliance (a KMS solution is indeed needed to be fully compliant). The solution's Security Agent resides in the DB engine and a CLI will help you for its management.